# What is the informal/impolite interrogative form of 이다?

Tags: verb, informal

What is the interrogative informal form of 이다? Is it 냐/이냐? I wasn't able to find this answer anywhere so here I am asking ^^

Comment: See the wiktionary entry: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%9D%B4%EB%8B%A4 (click     Selected forms of the adjective)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three common ones.

1. -(이)야?  네가 영훈이야? (Are you 영훈?)
2. -(이)니?  네가 영훈이니? (same)
3. -(이)냐?  네가 영훈이냐? (same)

-(이)야 is both an indicative and and interrogative form.
-(이)니 and -(이)냐 are interrogative only.  -(이)니? sounds more casual and friendly, while -(이)냐? may sound a bit rougher, like talking down.  Females tend to prefer the former and males the latter.

Comment: Thank you so much, but which is the former and which is the latter (sorry, I don't know what those words mean I'm not English)?

Comment: You're more than welcome, and I meant 이니 (the former) sounds softer and 이냐 a little rougher.